# Python Selenium cannot find an element (result empty)

Tags: python, selenium, find, element

Here is my python code

```
elements=driver.find_elements_by_id("folder_c0fb056b-f83a-495e-9db1-dd1b19942eaa")
print(elements)
```

the result is [ ]. The same way has worked for other parts of the website but when I get into a table inside the website, it does not work correctly. I could find and click some links prior to these command lines. Please look at the images I attached. When you look at HTML2, the white box is div "folder_c0fb056b-f83a-495e-9db1-dd1b19942eaa" shown in the last attached image (Webpage view). The rest blue boxes are the regions I am interested in. It looks like

```
<a id="rptReportFolders_ctl04_rptReports_ctl00_hlReportNameDescription" href="/da2/Reports/ReportResults.aspx?ReportID={b3583c5f-874b-4eca-9548-bf88f99ff7e6}">
    <b>AE-CR Log - Open Items / All Projects</b> 
</a>
```

[image: HTML]

[image: HTML2]

[image: Webpage view]

Comment: That id is a UUID and might be dynamically generated.  I would double check that the id exists at all when Selenium grabs it.  It might be different than when you look at it in a browser

Comment: Unlike find_element, find_elements will not throw an exception and return an empty list if the elements cannot be located. Can you try using explicit wait and wait for the elements to appear? Is the elements inside an iframe?

Comment: Brandon, I checked it again by opening another tab in a new browser. It has the same address (folder_c0fb056b-f83a-495e-9db1-dd1b19942eaa).

Comment: Satish, could you give me an example of doing so (explicit wait)? and no it is not in iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure, that id of the elements is not generic you can try to use this:

```
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='folder_c0fb056b-f83a-495e-9db1-dd1b19942eaa']/div/a")))
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
    if element.text == 'your text':
        element.click()
```

The main idea of this code snippet is to use `WebDriverWait` to wait at least 10 seconds until all elements will be present on the page and only then print the list of them. Also I have proposed another selector which will locate all `a` links.

***Note:*** you have to add some imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: I get a looooooong element like this..  [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="1dcfc5298680c5f2b9eb5ebf4af2a016", element="0.373763911577496-1")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="1dcfc5298680c5f2b9eb5ebf4af2a016", element="0.373763911577496-2")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="1dcfc5298680c5f2b9eb5ebf4af2a016", element="0.373763911577496-3")>,

Comment: Wow. that is what I exactly did now haha. It shows all the texts in the region! Is there any way that I can make the code further click into a specific text with hyperlink that I found?

Comment: Before asking further questions, I should have said this. You are a genius! Thank you.